# Check if string is key of interface

Tags: typescript-typings

Lets say we have interface like this:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  a: string;
  b: boolean;
}
```

and we would like to check whether certain value is keyof this interface during the runtime:

```js
const value = 'a';
const isValueKeyOfInteface = (value:string) => {
   ...?
}
```

While we would like to avoid manual constructing of an array like so

```js
const allowedKeys: (keyof MyInteface)[] = ['a', 'b'];
```

Is such a thing even doable in Typescript?

Comment: Nope, types and values are completely separated. I don't think there is a nice way to achieve this right now.